# android - Start intent from a BottomSheet fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-bottomsheetdialog

Im currently working on an app, that has a BottomSheet as a menu. The objective of this menu is to start intents depending on the item selected. I tried starting an Intent like below, however Android Studio says:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

- (Context!, Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
- (String!, Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to start an Intent from a class?

**frgBottomSheetDrawer.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        navDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem!!.itemId) {
                R.id.ndListFolder -> Intent(this, ndActFolder::class.java).also {
                    startActivity(it) 
                }
                R.id.ndListSettings -> Intent(this, ndActSettings::class.java).also {
                    startActivity(it) 
                }
                true
            }
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, container, false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clean solution.

We can write a cleaner Intent line:

```
this.startActivity(Intent(activity, actAbout::class.java))
```

In case you need the activity normally, we can write:

```
new intent = Intent(activity, actAbout::class.java))
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for events in bottom sheet from your activity by creating custom listener. You could do something like this:

In your BottomSheet:

```
var mListener: BottomSheetListener? = null

interface BottomSheetListener{
    fun onEventHappened(foo: Foo)
}

// Attach activity to your listener
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mListener = context as BottomSheetListener
}
```

In your Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BottomSheet.BottomSheetListener
```

It will want you to override `onEventHappened` method.

When you want to nagivate from your bottom sheet, run `mListener.onEventHappened(foo)` line in your BottomSheet class. It will trigger the `onEventHappened()` method in your Activity. Then you can start intents by your activity context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll give that a try. Are there any other ways to manage this? Like, directly inside of the fragment, or something else?

Comment: I found a cleaner solution, check the updated question. Thanks again for the answer!